# Is there a specific name given to the leaflet which only has job vacancies on it?

Tags: vocabulary

When I was buying some food in a supermarket, an assistant gave me a leaflet in A5 size.

There is some information about the job vacancies in this supermarket.

Can you tell me the name of this kind of leaflet which has job advertisements on it please?

Is it called job advertisement leaflet?

Thank you.

Kitty

Comment: I don't think there is. I think you just need to form an attributive noun for it as you did. Job vacancy/advertisement leaflet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people might call this a **want ad** (*ad* here is short for *advertisement*).

*Want ad* is a generic term used for the place where people post goods for sale or advertise for services wanted. Some newspapers have a want ad section. Some want ads have one particular focus, like automobiles for sale, or apartments for rent.

In the case of a local supermarket advertising local jobs, some might think *want ad* is too much of a stretch, and that want ads should be broader in scope than one local store. But published definitions allow for some wiggle room. M-W defines *want ad* as:

> a notice in a newspaper, magazine, etc., that lets people know about something that you want to buy or sell, a job that is available, etc.

While TFD says:

> a classified advertisement in a newspaper, magazine, etc, for something wanted, such as property or employment

Sometimes these are also referred to as **classified ads**. Personally, I would regard *classified ads* as something more widespread than a local store (I picture something like [this newspaper page](http://webspeakezine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/classified_ads1.jpg), e.g.), but I think *want ad* might work.